# Crystal Report creating a receipt register report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm creating a receipt register report. I have a database in SQL Server 2008 and I have table tblReceipt with the following fields:

```
**RefNo
AccCode1
AccTitle1
Debit
AccCode2
AccTitle2
Credit**
```

If I insert a transactions for examples someone donated `$500 with ReferenceNumber: 0001` and somebody pay for his debt with `ReferenceNumber: 0002 worth $600` then I need to record these in accounting.

The first ex. is

`**DEBIT($500)** in **Cash on Hand(AccountTitle)** and **Credit(-$500)** to **Donation(AccountTitle)**`

The second ex. is 
`**DEBIT($600)** in **Cash on hand** and **Credit(-$600)** in **Debt**`

and the table will looks like this

**RefNo        AccCode1        AccTitle1          Debit       AccCode2       AccTitle2       Credit**

0001          1101                Cash on Hand    $500        3100                Donation         -$500

0002          1101                    Cash on Hand    $600        3200                Debt               -$600

and In crystal report I design it look like this

**RefNo      Cash on Hand[1101]         Donation[3100]      Debt[3200]**

0001        $500                               
-$500

0002        $600                                
                
                 -$600

Now if we look in the two records they are correct. But my problem is when someone donated and also pay his debt in a single transaction. My table looks like this

**RefNo        AccCode1        AccTitle1          Debit       AccCode2       AccTitle2       Credit**

0001          1101                Cash on Hand    $500        3100                Donation         -$500

0002          1101                    Cash on Hand    $600        3200                Debt               -$600

0003          1101
               Cash on Hand     $1100      3100                 Donation            -$500

0003          1101
               Cash on Hand     $1100      3100                 Debt                           -$600

But my crystal report looks like this

**RefNo      Cash on Hand [1101]         Donation [3100]      Debt [3200]**

0001          $500                                 -$500

0002          $600                                                                  -$600

0003          $1100                                 -$500

0003          $1100                                                                  -$600

This is not what I want. Because its duplicate the referencenumber. and also If I will try to compute the total of the account(Cash on Hand) I will have a wrong output.

I want my report look like this.

**RefNo      Cash on Hand [1101]         Donation [3100]      Debt [3200]**

0001          $500                                 -$500

0002          $600                                                                  -$600

0003          $1100                               -$500                        -$600

How can I achieve this? Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Note: examples in your question are confusing below answer is the example for implementation
```

follow below process to get required output:

1. Create a group with `RefNo` and `supress` the header.
2. Create 3 formulas `@Cash on Hand` , `@ Donation` and `@Debt` and place in details and supress the detail section

@Cash on Hand

```
if(AccCode1=1101) and ISNULL(Cash on Hand)
then 0
else Cash on Hand
```

@ Donation

```
if (AccCode2=3100) and ISNULL( Donation )
the 0
else Donation
```

@Debt

```
if (AccCode2=3200) and ISNULL( Debt )
    the 0
    else Debt
```

now take the summary of 3 formulas in the footer and you get the required output.

Edit-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Place `Ref no` in detail to the leftmost part of the report.

now for `Cash in Hand` in group footer write below formula.

```
sum({@Cash on Hand},{Refgroup})/Count({Ref},{Refgrop})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try this, just to clarify, Should I need to suppress the group header and details section? If yes, where should I display the details?

Comment: yes you need to supress details and group header... and no need to display detail... take the summary of details in group footer that will give you required output.

Comment: Hi, I just want to ask what do you mean by this condition? if(AccCode1=1101) and ISNULL(Cash on Hand)
then 0
else Cash on Hand

Comment: In your table there is possibility that `refno` can have values for some columns and there can be no value if no value then using `0` for that record so that when we summarize we get correct sumary... and coming to `AccCode1` I didn't understand in your answer hence mentioned in note at starting that its an example... change as per your requirement.. hope I made it clear

Comment: I'm just confuse, What should I need to put in ISNULL() and else condition? a fields?

Comment: if you see your question for `002` there is no `Donation` what does that mean? there is no value for that ref number hence checking for null... if you directly place a field then no need to check for null but in a formula need to check null condition

Comment: In my example 0002, I don't have values in donation because ref. no.: 0002 don't have a transaction that refer to DONATION and I just need to leave it blank.

Comment: you need it as blank.. my code will show it as `0` why becuase to get the result of `  $1100  ` for `003` I gave this code...

Comment: Sorry I have a typographic error in my the last table I made, I change the value of 0003 Cash on hand Value to $1100.

Comment: thanks for you idea I think I know what I need to do. I understood what you mean. Thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: I did what I understood in your explanation, but still i did not achieve the report I want. It hides the row that has duplicate refno. It cause the details of duplicate refno. is not displaying in the report. what should I do?

Comment: can post a screenshot of what you have achieved and where is the problem? will try to help

Comment: Sorry I can't, I need to earn at least 10 reputation to post some images. And I'm just new user in this website.

Comment: I have upvoted your questions so that you can get 10 reputation now try to paste the wcreenshot

Comment: Hello @Siva I already solved this problem. I think I just left something so I did'nt get the correct output but its okay now. But can you still help me again? I have problem again in displaying details to this report. See the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801969/crystal-report-creating-a-receipt-register-report-2

Comment: Hi siva I just want to ask again if you don't mind, In your answer What do you mean get the summary of the 3 formulas? What I did is right click the formula and insert summary is that correct?

Comment: Okay, I calculate it sum and place it in group footer but it really getting the sum of each refno.

Comment: did get you? ` but it really getting the sum of each refno`

Comment: For example my table example in above it get the sum of $1100 and display in my report as $2200

Comment: Edited my answer.... your issue here is you have duplicate for `Cash in hand` at the same time no duplicate values for `Donation` and `Debit`.. check my edited answer.. this should work

Comment: How can I write the formula for the Cash on Hand, its only a summary when I right click on it theres no edit formula.

Comment: In this case don't do by right click but create a formula and go to report fields then implement my formula

Comment: Argh ! You are really good. I did it I understood what you said. THANKS YOUR AWESOME :D

Comment: if solution is useful you can accept as answer.. so that others can use it.