# Crystal Report creating a receipt register report 2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, accounting

This question is related to my first question, see it here: [Crystal Report creating a receipt register report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740613/crystal-report-creating-a-receipt-register-report)

I already done some parts of my report with the help of a good person(Siva) but I'm on much bigger problem I think. It's about my sundries section.

In my table

[image]

and I want to display my report to look like this.

[image]

And this is what I'm getting...

[image]

You can see in my table that the record with RefNo: 1003 has a lots of account that has been paid. Unfortunately the reports I'm getting has no record of AccCode: 4200 Housing Loan with a credit of -$40.

I don't know how to achieve this again... I'm placing all the details in a group footer of field name RefNo.

Please someone can help me to this, you can just give me some idea and I try to handle it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: since you are placing in group footer I guess it is taking only `last record` that is the reason you are able to see only `4500`.. place the same details in group header and let me know the result.. will try to provide you the solution

Comment: I did what you said, I placed the same details in group header but there are no records appear in my sundries section....

Comment: one wayout is use sub report for sundries section and place it in group footer... you will get desired output

Comment: Yah I'm thinking it last night, and that's what I'm doing right now I hope its really work :D Thanks a lot I hope I can say this personally. :)

Comment: I am sure this will work... try the option

Comment: Why if I try to view my subreport, not yet integrating in my main report it shows correct output and base in my sql query condition but when I insert it into my main report It ignore my sql condition. It display all the details.

Comment: have you linked main report and sub report?

Comment: nope what field name should I link?

Comment: Any filed that is common... and also apply same level of grouping and filtering as you applied in main report for sundries.. Right click on sub report and linnk through `Change Sub report link`

Comment: I link it to refno and display all the details. Unfortunately, it still ignore my sql condition

Comment: I already have another sub report in my main report its a sundries summary and even though I did not link it to my main report my query condition still executed.

Comment: eventhough you don't link query will be executed and data will be displayed.. linking is necessary to get the required data...link the main report to sub report and give the same conditions in sub report that you gave in main report.. answer is broad... hard explain in comments